# How to add more than one root element into Spring-WS webservice envelope's body?

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I asked almost similar question, but more detailed ... so sorry for repeating.
I need to have Spring-ws web service operation which has two root elements in body, like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pow="http://comp.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
         <pow:authData>
         <!-- elements -->
         </pow:authData>
         <pow:processRequestData>
         <!-- elements -->
         </pow:processRequestData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But Spring-ws always generates (from xsd) envelope only with one root element which included two others:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pow="http://comp.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pow:processRequestRequest>
         <pow:authData>
         <!-- elements -->
         </pow:authData>
         <pow:processRequestData>
         <!-- elements -->
         </pow:processRequestData>
      </pow:processRequestRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to create envelope body with two root elements `authData` and `rocessRequestData` instead of one? Is it possible?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly: it isn't possible.

In the end `<soapenv:Body>` is extracted as a top-level XML document. That's why it is called `payload`.

The top-level document can have only one root element.

It isn't Spring WS restrictions. That's how SOAP works independently of the platform.

Comment: Artem, thank you. But i have service which looks like: `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sin="http://comp.com/2015/webservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <min:Elem1>
      </min:Elem1>
      <min:Elem2>
      </min:Elem2>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope` . I see it in SOAP UI.

Comment: OK. How about do not generate WSDL, but have the static one. Then you can do anything you want/need. Of course there will be some chalanges on request to parse such an XML properly...

Comment: Artem, please, describe or post some links which help me to understand offered approach.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help so much here, because I'm still swimming in the subject, if the question is out of the typical, standard configuration. Consider to use `SimpleWsdl11Definition` - http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure

Comment: Artem, thank you. I'll try `<static-wsdl>` definition. Also i'll be glad for any other advices.